# RTC clock time sync with the Linux time on Startup

Tags: time, clock

The RTC remembers its time set, and how does the linux kernel gets this time from dev/rtc and set it as the linux time. In other words on boot up - when does kernel reads the rtc and updates its linux time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux kernel has following option `RTC_HCTOSYS` to restore system time from RTC on startup.

> If you say yes here, the system time (wall clock) will be set using
>   the value read from a specified RTC device. This is useful to avoid
>   unnecessary fsck runs at boot time, and to network better.

Another way is to use a startup script, that will use `hwclock` utility to set system time from RTC.

```
hwclock --hctosys
```

Comment: simply running the hwclock , syncs the rtc clock to that of the linux.